# Syntax of DriveApp makeCopy (name, destination)

Tags: google-apps-script

Rather that using:

```
var copyDoc = DocsList.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy(docName).getId();
```

I would like to use:

```
var copyDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy(name, destination).getId();
```

I can't get the syntax of destination right, is this the folder path or the folder ID or something else? An example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I know this questions a little old but hopefully this will help future readers.  I had the same query and after a couple of guesses figured it out.  Basically you have to think of folders in Google Drive in the same way as any other object such as a Google Document or Spreadsheet, i.e. the folders aren't real, they're just objects with Google ID references.

The simple way I solved this was to create my required folder structure and then note down the Google URL ID of the folder, this can be found in the address bar URL when navigating the folder, for example:

```
 https://drive.google.com/a/[your company]/?usp=chrome_app&usp=chrome_app#folders/ABCDEFGHIJKL12345
                                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In the example URL above the underlined text would be the unique ID.

Within your script you can then use the `getFolderById()` method to set the destination, for example:

```
var file = "New File Name";
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("**[Your ID From Above]**");
file.makeCopy(file, folder);
```

There are other methods for obtaining the folder by name, but those involve iterating through each folder one at a time drastically increasing the amount of code needed.

Comment: Even longer now since the answer, but hopefully helping the next reader. Be mindful that a document/spreadsheet/slide can be stored in multiple folders (each referencing the document unique ID).